# Subtract values in one column of lists from another using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a multiIndexed data frame where I want to apply a function to one column, using information from another column. Here is some example data:

```
                ind pos                          log
x   y       z           
33.0 7.0    0.0 21  (997.232, 217.786, 26.6823) [1, 0, 0]
            0.0 22  (992.761, 217.274, 26.6758) [1, 0, 0]
            0.0 23  (998.916, 217.354, 27.9557) [1, 0, 0]
2.0 33.0    2.0 63  (66.6064, 999.717, 70.8408) [0, 1, 0]
            2.0 64  (65.7294, 999.793, 72.4056) [0, 1, 0]
```

I want to apply the function

```
pos - 1000*log
```

to each row of the data frame.  What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: what would be the sample output for the first row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `apply`, as the other answer suggests. You should instead extract these columns as new DataFrames and perform vectorized arithmetic on them.

```
i = pd.DataFrame(df['pos'].tolist())
j = pd.DataFrame(df['log'].tolist())
```

...Or you could also use numpy arrays to do the same thing:

```
i = np.array(df['pos'].tolist())
j = np.array(df['log'].tolist())
```

```
df['result'] = (i - 1000 * j).tolist()
```

As a side note, please consider separating each column of lists/iterables into multiple columns with a single scalar value. Performance matters, and with columns of objects, you end up killing performance unless you use trickery (like in this post), or else use the slow loopy apply functions that do not scale at all.

Answer (score 1):

Using `zip` with for loop

```
[(np.array(x)-1000*np.array(y)).tolist() for x , y in zip(df.log,df.pos)]
Out[474]: [[-997231.0, -217786.0, -26682.300000000003], [-992760.0, -217274.0, -26675.8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def pos_minus_log(row):
    return tuple([row.pos[i] - 1000*row.log[i] for i in range(3)])
```

Then: `df['new_col'] = df.apply(pos_minus_log, axis = 1)`

Answer (score 0):

In one line you could write:

```
df["res"] = df.apply(lambda row: tuple(np.subtract(list(row.pos),[e*1000 for e in row.log] )),axis = 1)
```

This adds a column in which it stores the result for each row.